# reorder div with css

Tags: html, css

I have divs sorted 1, 2, 3 ... as html layout

HTML:

```
<div class="bigdiv">
    <div class="div1">div 1</div>
    <div class="div2">div 2</div>
    <div class="div3">div 3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.div1 {
    float: left; 
}

.div2 {
    float: left;     
 }

 .div3 {
    float: left;     
 }
```

How can I **reorder divs** to this **layout with CSS**

```
<div class="bigdiv">
    <div class="div3">div 3</div>
    <br>
    <div class="div1">div 1</div>
    <div class="div2">div 2</div>
</div>
```

by CSS (float, :after, :before)

My try:

```
.div3 {
    float: right; 
} 
.div3:before {
    content: '\A\A';
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: CSS is not the tool for this job; use javascript/jquery if you need to manipulate the DOM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try to play around the `display` property and use this style:

CSS

```
.bigdiv { display:table; }

.div1, .div2 { float: left; }

.div3 {  display: table-header-group; }
```

---

Live example: http://jsbin.com/axekof/2/edit

Note the `display:table;` applied to the main wrapper and the display property applied to the `.div3`. The example should work even on `IE8` (didn't tested)

As a sidenote, for `.div3` you may use both `display: table-caption` and `display: table-header-group`, but there's a slight difference: with the first property, the parent element wraps only `.div1` and `.div2` while, with the latter, the container wraps all the children elements (try to apply a border to the `.bigdiv` so you can clearly see the difference)

Answer (score 11):

You can do this with the [CSS Flexible Box Layout Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/)

> The ‘order’ property controls the order in which flex items appear
>   within their flex container, by assigning them to ordinal groups.
>
> A flex container will lay out its content starting from the lowest
>   numbered ordinal group and going up. Items with the same ordinal group
>   are laid out in the order they appear in the source document. This
>   also affects the painting order [CSS21], exactly as if the elements
>   were reordered in the document. ([W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#order-property))

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/BNyM6/)

### CSS (Without browser specifics)

```
.bigdiv {

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    }

.div1 {
    order: 2;
 }

.div2 {
    order: 3;
 }

.div3 {
    order: 1;
 }
```

Comment: is there a way to have a linebreak after div3?

Comment: intresting solution (it is not working in jsfidle for me) ... I will try to test it, `display: table;` is working for me, +1 for efford

Comment: Wonderful and elegant solution. The flex property is a fine addition to CSS that I cannot stop using. It is simple yet powerful. This should be the accepted answer. Worked perfectly for me on the first try.

Answer (score 2):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="bigdiv">
    <div class="div1">div 1</div>
    <div class="div2">div 2</div>
    <div class="div3">div 3</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.bigdiv {
    display:table;
    width:100%; 
}

.div1 {
    display: table-row-group;
}

.div2 {
    display: table-footer-group;
 }

 .div3 {
    display: table-header-group;
 }
```

The result will be:

div 3

div 1

div 2

**And for those pesky early versions of Internet Explorer...** [Source](http://tanalin.com/en/articles/css-block-order/)

Old browsers IE6 and IE7 do not support CSS properties of display: table family.

Also, IE8 has a dynamic rendering bug that appears in some cases: if a block to move contains preudo-table elements (display: table*) (this is the only buggy case noticed currently), some pseudo-table cells (such cells as well as cells count are different each time the page is reloaded) may disappear randomly when the page is initially rendered.

So, for IE8 and lower, we can override CSS rules that make blocks tably, and additionally move blocks to required positions in DOM tree of HTML document with JavaScript instead of CSS:

```
/**
 * Reorders sibling elements in DOM tree according to specified order.
 * @param {Array} elems Sibling elements in desired block order.
 */
function reorderElements(elems) {
    var count = elems.length;

    if (!count) {
        return;
    }

    var parent = elems[0].parentNode;

    for (var i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        parent.insertBefore(elems[i], parent.firstChild);
    }
}

// If IE8 or lower
if (document.all && !document.addEventListener) {
    var blocks = [
        document.getElementById('div3'),
        document.getElementById('div2'),
        document.getElementById('div1')
    ];

    reorderElements(blocks);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that with just CSS as I see you are manipulating the DOM. However if you would still want to achieve that you would need to use `position:relative` for bigdiv and `position:absolute` for `.div1` `.div2` and `.div3`, which are actually the children of `.bigdiv`. You would then need to use `left`, `top`, `right`, and `bottom` properties to style them as needed.